# How to convert Objective-C string into a C string?

Tags: objective-c, c, string

I need to convert an C-String into an NSString.
How do I do this?
I know how to convert it the OTHER WAY,

```
NSString *hello = @"Hello!";
const char *buffer;
buffer = [schoolName cStringUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"C-String is: %s", buffer);
```

However, how do I do it Objective-C string (NSString) into a **NULL-TERMINATED** string.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`const char *buffer = [hello UTF8String];` will do what you're looking for.

Now to answer the new (and very different) question:

If you have, for example, `const char *cstring = "hello world";` you can create an `NSString *` with it through: `NSString *nsstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", cstring];`

There are, of course, other ways to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Doesn't this do the same thing as `buffer = [schoolName cStringUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];`?

Comment: I've never used `cStringUsingEncoding` but I use `UTF8String` quite regularly and I've never seen it not be NULL terminated.

Comment: I'm sorry, your answer **IS NOT INCORRECT**, but I fear that I have wrote my QUESTION wrong! I need to do the exact opposite, IE, I need to turn my Objective-C object INTO C. I'm really sorry about the mistake.

Comment: I'm sorry, but my answer was absolutely correct for the question you posted!

Comment: I know, I'm really sorry about that. Question should be fixed at this point. Up-vote for you for a good answer.

Comment: Shorter: `[NSString stringWithUTF8String:cstring]`, or the new Clang "boxed expression", `NSString *nsstring = @(cstring)`.

Comment: Thank you so much for being flexible. Answer accepted as correct.

Comment: How if UTF8String is clamping the string and adding a ... colon instead where it considers? @Sir_Mr_Bman

Answer (score 3):

```
NSString* str = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char *)]
```

or

```
NSString* str = [NSString stringWithCString:(const char *) encoding:(NSStringEncoding)]
```

or

```
NSString* str = [NSString stringWithCharacters:(const unichar *) length:(NSUInteger)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
- (wchar_t*)getWideString
{
    const char* temp = [schoolName cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    int buflen = strlen(temp)+1; //including NULL terminating char
    wchar_t* buffer = malloc(buflen * sizeof(wchar_t));
    mbstowcs(buffer, temp, buflen);
    return buffer;
};
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but as listed above, there is a slightly easier way of doing it. Up-vote for an answer that works, and for not being afraid to use a lot of cod.e